# comparing accuracy for calculating floating point with x*0.1 and x/10.0

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy, numerical-methods

which expression is more accurate and why? I think if it is not 10.0 and it's 2^k for some integer k, then we just need to subtract k in the exponent. But there is 10, I can not think of a way of comparing them...

Comment: Hint: Assuming IEEE-754 binary floating-point, what is known about the accuracy of multiplication and division? What is known about the accuracy with which the literal constants `0.1` and `10.0` can be represented in any of the IEEE-754 binary floating-point formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation can be done exactly in java's BigDecimal. All finite double numbers convert exactly to BigDecimal. Based on these two ideas, it is possible to compare the two methods:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] main) {
    testDivide(1);
    testDivide(10);
    testDivide(1e6);
    Random rand = new Random(3);
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
      testDivide(rand.nextDouble());
    }
    System.out.println("Equal results: "+equals);
    System.out.println("Divide by 10 better: "+divBetter);
    System.out.println("Multiply by 0.1 better: "+multBetter);
  }

  private static int equals;
  private static int divBetter;
  private static int multBetter;

  public static void testDivide(double x) {
    BigDecimal tenth = new BigDecimal("0.1");
    double mult = x * 0.1;
    double div = x / 10;
    BigDecimal exact = new BigDecimal(x).multiply(tenth);
    BigDecimal multError = exact.subtract(new BigDecimal(mult)).abs();
    BigDecimal divError = exact.subtract(new BigDecimal(div)).abs();
    int comparison = divError.compareTo(multError);
    if(comparison == 0){
      equals++;
    } else if(comparison < 0){
      divBetter++;
    } else {
      multBetter++;
    }
  }
}
```

I got:

```
Equal results: 649781
Divide by 10 better: 350222
Multiply by 0.1 better: 0
```

As hinted in @njuffa's comment, the multiply method can never be better. 10 is exactly representable as a double, and divide is required to produce the closest representable number to the result of the real number divide. The multiply method may not get the closest to the exact divide result because of the inherent rounding error on converting 0.1 to double.